# How to prevent assiging similar types?

Tags: typescript

How do I prevent TypeScript from allowing assigning similar but different *types* to a declared variable?

Consider following classes:

```
class Person {
 private firstName;
 private lastName;

 public setFirstName(firstName: string): void {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }

 public setLastName(lastName: string): void {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }

 public getFullName(): string {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
 }
}

class Man extends Person {
 public getFullName(): string {
  return 'Mr. ' + super.getFullName();
 }
}

class Woman extends Person {
 public getFullName(): string {
  return 'Ms. ' + super.getFullName();
 }
}
```

Following works:

```
var jon: Man = new Woman();
var arya: Woman = new Man();
```

The reason for above to work is that properties and methods of both `Man` and `Woman` types are similar. If I added some property or method unique to either `Man` or `Woman`, it'll throw an error as expected.

How do I get TypeScript to throw errors if someone assign different *types* with similar signatures to variables declared for another *type*?

Comment: Its all about convenience : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

Answer (score 5):

This is by design, TypeScript won't throw errors if the types match.

> One of TypeScript's core principles is that type-checking focuses on the 'shape' that values have. This is sometimes called "duck typing" or "structural subtyping".
>
> http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces

As a result, this is something that would be checked at runtime.

```
var arya: Woman = new Man();

if (arya instanceof Man) {
    throw new Error("Dude looks like a lady! *guitar riff*");
}
```

TypeScript understands `instanceof` so it can be used to cast types as well.

```
var jon: Man = new Woman();

if (jon instanceof Man) {
    // The type of `jon` is Man
    jon.getFullName();
}

if (jon instanceof Woman) {
    // The type of `jon` is Woman
    jon.getFullName();
}
```

Lastly you can also use type guards available in 1.6.

```
function isMan(a: Person): a is Man {
    return a.getFullName().indexOf('Mr. ') !== -1;
}

var arya: Woman = new Man();

if(isMan(arya)) {
    // The type of `arya` is Man
    arya.getFullName();
}
```

Comment: Agreed, their implementations are different, but their types are the same.

Answer (score 0):

So it works by design (you can't escape it). From the official documentation:

Classes work similarly to object literal types and interfaces with one exception: they have both a static and an instance type. When comparing two objects of a class type, only members of the instance are compared. Static members and constructors do not affect compatibility.

```
class Animal {
    feet: number;
    constructor(name: string, numFeet: number) { }
}

class Size {
    feet: number;
    constructor(numFeet: number) { }
}

var a: Animal;
var s: Size;

a = s;  //OK
s = a;  //OK
```